# Skype channel proactive message request get 500 (Internal Server Error) after some time

Tags: c#, botframework, skype-bots

I am developing a bot for Skype channel, which can send proactive messages.

I followed the example project https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages , and this works for my need.

I host my bot on a shared hosting service, not Azure.

I registered my bot in Azure Channel Registration, tested on skype. Bot responds to me, and when i send request to proactive endpoint, i get proactive message. Everything is fine.

Then i realized, after some time, proactive request get 500 (Internal Server Error). After that, i typed something to bot from skype, then send proactive request again, bot sended the proactive message.

I investigated this issue, and found two things. First, enable AlwaysOn within IIS, but i am on shared hosting, i can't do that. Second, send some requests to bot regularly to keep bot alive.

Than i noticed, i can do this with DirectLine channel. I set up my code to start conversation, send some message, and receive it before i send proactive notification. It was easy to start conversation from DirectLine, i sended a message, and i received response. Since this is a request to bot, i think this can solve my 500(Internal Server Error) response status with proactive. But it didn't.

I can only receive proactive messages in Skype, only if i type something to bot from skype in short period of time. Otherwise, Skype proactive message request gets 500 error.

I don't know how to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I'm also working with this user in [their duplicate GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/85).

This sounds like it's possibly a [TrustServiceUrl Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) (despite the 500 vs 401 error message).

You can fix it by adding Skype to the list of trusted URLs:

```
var serviceUrl = <GetThisFrom Activity.ServiceUrl>;

MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
```

[Here's a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs) to the library, if that helps. Otherwise, [browsing these issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?q=label%3A%22Trust+Service+URL%22+is%3Aclosed) should help.

#### Note to others:

This "Trust Service URL Issue" doesn't apply to just Skype. This happens for lots of other URLs when trying to use Proactive messaging. Just replace `serviceUrl` with whatever is appropriate for your use case. And yes, if you're using multiple channels, you can add multiple URLs when using `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl()` by calling it multiple times.

Here's [the method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.microsoftappcredentials.trustserviceurl?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). Note: you can add expiration for this, as well.

[I've submitted a PR for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1262), which so far has resulted in [some updated docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors)